# Batch processing notifications of job tracking

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment we're using three nested foreach loops to get the information to run the batch. However I'm fairly sure we could get the information with a single MySQL statement with joins and sub-queries.

We have about 30 categories with 2000 users. Our aim is about 100 categories with 100000 users though so obviously the foreach loops are not ideal (even now they take about a minute to run).

**Circumstance:**
 Users want to be notified if there is work available for a trade they can do in a certain area

**Goal:**
 Batch process (daily, weekly, etc) notifications to be put in outbox

**Technology:**
 PHP, MySQL

**What I have so far:**

**Database:**

```
 "table.notification_options" : [id][user_id][category]
 "table.user" : [id][user_id][method_of_contact][contact_frequency][center_of_work_area_long][center_of_work_area_lat][distance_from_center]
 "table.work" : [id][post_date][longitude][latitude][category]
```

**Code:**

```
foreach user{
    foreach category tracked{
        foreach job in category posted <> $current_date-$batch_frequency{
            if job inside workspace{
                notify_user(job);
            }
        }
   }
}
```

The desired result is an array of arrays of job_ids with user_id as the key
[user_id]=>{jobs}

**e.g.**

```
    {
        [user1]{
                 job1,
                 job4,
                 job28
               },
        [user34]{
                 job3,
                 job4,
                 job34,
                 job78
                }
     {
```

**EDIT:**

I've got it a bit more efficient where I can select all the jobs for one user. But it still requires a foreach user.

```
   $category_id = get_category_from_notification_options($userid);
   $user_distance = get_user_work_distance($userid);
    "SELECT DISTINCT work.ID as workID, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-46.409939) ) * cos( radians( jobs.lat ) ) * cos( radians( jobs.lng ) - radians(168.366180) ) + sin( radians(-46.409939) ) * sin( radians( jobs.lat ) ) ) ) 
        AS distance 
        FROM work,user
        WHERE work.categoryID == $category_id
        HAVING distance < $user_distance
        ORDER BY distance";
```

Comment: Goal: Batch process (daily, weekly, etc) notifications to be put in outbox - ???
Outbox?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question. To clarify: users track when work becomes available in an area they designate (radius from their location). This script's job is to run at a certain interval and collect information on all the jobs that have been posted in their area since last time it ran and notify them. The outbox is the sending queue for messages to go to the users - like all email/txt etc works.

Comment: The SQL I have suggested will do this in pretty much a single SQL statement, with just any formatting done in php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do it the other way around to make it more efficient. Below i will show you the process I used to create the query. So only the final query is what you need. But I explain the steps so perhaps it will help you in the future.

First I would select all jobs. Most likely there are a lot less jobs then users if your goal is 100.000 users.

```
select JOB.id, JOB.category
FROM table.work JOB
```

Now we have all the jobs, lets see which users want to be notified about it.

```
select JOB.id, JOB.category, NOTIFY.user_id
FROM table.work JOB
LEFT JOIN table.notification_options NOTIFY
ON JOB.category=NOTIFY.category
WHERE NOTIFY.user_id IS NOT NULL
```

This creates a list with for each job, all the userID's that want to be notified about it. I added the `WHERE` clause to remove all jobs from the list nobody wants to see.
Now we can `JOIN` the users table to get user details aswell.

```
select JOB.id
     , JOB.post_date
     , JOB.longitude
     , JOB.latitude
     , USR.user_id
     , USR.method_of_contact
     , USR.contact_frequency
     , USR.center_of_work_area_long
     , USR.center_of_work_area_lat
     , USR.distance_from_center
     , ((ACOS(SIN(USR.center_of_work_area_lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(JOB.latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(USR.center_of_work_area_lat * PI() / 180) * COS(JOB.latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((USR.center_of_work_area_long – JOB.longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`
FROM table.work JOB
LEFT JOIN table.notification_options NOTIFY
ON JOB.category=NOTIFY.category
LEFT JOIN table.user USR
ON NOTIFY.user_id=USR.user_id
WHERE NOTIFY.user_id IS NOT NULL
HAVING `distance`<=USR.distance_from_center
ORDER BY USR.user_id ASC, distance ASC
```

I included the distance in the query. Notice that I use `HAVING` to check if the distance is smaller then the user supplied. If you would add it to the `WHERE` clause you would get an error saying `distance` is an unknown column.
I also added the `ORDER BY` class to first sort it on user ID and then on distance. This will make it easier to create the array you want in PHP.

Now there are a lot of ways to implement the daily/weekly intervals. One of them is to create seperate scripts for each interval and only select the users that set it.
For example, you could create a script 'daily.php' which you run each day and have the following query

```
select JOB.id
     , JOB.post_date
     , JOB.longitude
     , JOB.latitude
     , USR.user_id
     , USR.method_of_contact
     , USR.contact_frequency
     , USR.center_of_work_area_long
     , USR.center_of_work_area_lat
     , USR.distance_from_center
     , ((ACOS(SIN(USR.center_of_work_area_lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(JOB.latitude * PI() / 180) + COS(USR.center_of_work_area_lat * PI() / 180) * COS(JOB.latitude * PI() / 180) * COS((USR.center_of_work_area_long – JOB.longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS `distance`
FROM table.work JOB
LEFT JOIN table.notification_options NOTIFY
ON JOB.category=NOTIFY.category
LEFT JOIN table.user USR
ON NOTIFY.user_id=USR.user_id
WHERE NOTIFY.user_id IS NOT NULL
AND USR.contact_frequency = 'daily'
HAVING `distance`<=USR.distance_from_center
ORDER BY USR.user_id ASC, distance ASC
```

Now we have the query, lets create the PHP code for it. We can loop trough all the rows and create the array. Obviously instead of creating the array you could also directly process the result. Because if you create an array first, you do need to loop trough that array again afterwards.

```
<?php
$arNotify = array();
foreach ($queryresult as $row) {
  $userid = $row->user_id;
  $jobid = $row->id;

  //check if there is an entry for the user in the database, else create it
  if (!array_key_exists($userid, $arNotify))
    $arNotify[$userid] = array();

  //and then push the job
  $arNotify[$userid][] = $jobid;

  //the array is being created, but I still like to process the job directly
  //notify_user($userid, $jobid);

}

var_dump($arNotify);
?>
```

There you go, the array as you want with the jobs sorted on closest first.

Comment: Thanks. To bad you didnt award the bounty though

Comment: It is too bad! I didn't realise it would expire, sorry Hugo.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me as though the distance you pick up is taken from the users table anyway (distance_from_center field?)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ser.user_id, work.ID as workID, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-46.409939) ) * cos( radians( jobs.lat ) ) * cos( radians( jobs.lng ) - radians(168.366180) ) + sin( radians(-46.409939) ) * sin( radians( jobs.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM notification_options
INNER JOIN jobs ON notification_options.category = jobs.category
INNER JOIN user ON notification_options.user_id = user.user_id
HAVING distance < user.distance_from_center
ORDER BY distance
```

EDIT - If you just want a list of jobs for each user in distance order (which if needs be you could explode to an array for processing in php - although probably easier to use the above query to build up the array) then you could use something like this:-

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(workID ORDER BY distance)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT ser.user_id, work.ID as workID, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(-46.409939) ) * cos( radians( jobs.lat ) ) * cos( radians( jobs.lng ) - radians(168.366180) ) + sin( radians(-46.409939) ) * sin( radians( jobs.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM notification_options
INNER JOIN jobs ON notification_options.category = jobs.category
INNER JOIN user ON notification_options.user_id = user.user_id
HAVING distance < user.distance_from_center) Sub1
```